# Failed to load resource 404 (Not Found)

Tags: gulp, jhipster, browser-sync

I've cloned the latest version the JHipster Registry and imported that into Spring Tool Suite.  I am able to successfully start the registry and I see the shared token in the environment configuration endpoint.

(generator-jhipster:3.4.0)

I've created a sample gateway with the following config:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.4.0",
    "baseName": "gateway",
    "packageName": "com.sample.gateway",
    "packageFolder": "com/sample/gateway",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "cassandra",
    "devDatabaseType": "cassandra",
    "prodDatabaseType": "cassandra",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "jwtSecretKey": "487569610b520174d948be43fceeabc68716ceaf",
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ],
    "enableSocialSignIn": false
  }
}
```

I've created a sample app with the following config:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.4.0",
    "baseName": "app",
    "packageName": "com.sample.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/sample/app",
    "serverPort": "9002",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "databaseType": "cassandra",
    "devDatabaseType": "cassandra",
    "prodDatabaseType": "cassandra",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "jwtSecretKey": "e8aaff85cec927d25851087096331152d8a8c5a2",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ],
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false
  }
}
```

I am able to star the gateway and see that it connects to the registry.  I am also able to start the app and see that it too connects to the registry.

However, whenever I run gulp and load the main page, I see the following errors in the console:

```
http://localhost:9000/app/services/profiles/profile.service.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/app/services/profiles/page-ribbon.directive.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/app/services/user/user.service.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/app/services/auth/register.service.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/app/services/auth/principal.service.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/app/app.module.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
....
```

**What is causing these errors to appear?**

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing but I cannot figure out why it is not able to find these files.  I can browse the file system, and they are clearly there.

Edit:

**I've noticed that even though I am hitting the url from Gulp + browsersync, I am seeing resource requests getting to the spring server.  This doesn't seem correct and makes me believe there is an issue in gulp/browsersync/proxy.**

Comment: Are you able to access your gateway correctly without using `gulp`? And concerning your resources requests on the Spring server, this should be OK, BrowserSync needs to read them from there

Comment: @Julien - I spent all day trying to figure this out and got no where.  I shutdown my computer and then came back the next day and it was working... This wasn't the first time I've seen this issue, so I'm going to keep this around.  Things to try next time: 1) Different browsers 2) Different machine connecting to served resources